# Problem to sends data with json in python (ut8 error)

Tags: python, json, sockets, encoding, decode

I have an issue with a script, it's a reserve backdoor, it's working fine between my host machine and my VM Kali but between my host machine and my VM Windows, I got an error message which says ""UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 58: invalid start byte". 
I'm using Json to transferred and received data.
I understand that is a decode error but I really don't know how to fix this.

My parts of code which dumps the data to send and receive with json :

```
    def reliable_send(self, data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    self.connection.send(json_data)

def reliable_receive(self):
    json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
    return json.loads(json_data)

def execute_remotely(self, command):
    self.reliable_send(command)
    return self.reliable_receive()
```

Thanks for you help :)

EDIT : My error message :

```
    C:\Python27>backdoor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\backdoor.py", line 39, in <module>
    my_backdoor.run()
File "C:\Python27\backdoor.py", line 34, in run
    self.reliable_send(command_result)
File "C:\Python27\backdoor.py", line 17, in reliable_send
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 58: invalid stard byte
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I edited my message and added the error message ! I think it's encoded in ascii by default, I am wrong? @snakecharmerb

Comment: I've passed ensure_ascii to False in __init__.py in Windows and now the error message come from my host machin BUT if I do a print(json_data) I can see the result but all the "é" character are now "?" @snakecharmerb